# Regular expression to get the following string of particular characters for a specified tag

Tags: regex

```
*C106 XYZ TechSolutions Ltd. 27 XY Street ABC TUZB5 TX 0 *B050 ABC ABCSolutions Ltd. 72 XY Street ABC TUZB5 TX 0
```

I wanted to have the text which is following *C106 i.e (XYZ TechSolutions Ltd. 27 XY Street ABC TUZB5 TX 0). I used this regex

```
(?<=C106\s).*$
```

but it takes in text from *B050 as well in output. Any advise would be really helpful.

Comment: Try: `(?<=C106\s).+?(?=\s\*[A-Z])`

Comment: What defines where `C106` should end; numbers, spaces, end of string, other? Depending on where maybe split on each `*` then check the start is `C106`?

Comment: Yes, Spaces defines the end of the string.

Comment: @anubhava - thanks for  providing the regex. It worked as per my expectations.